# creating a color that will be shared by Mac and iOS code

Tags: iphone, macos, ios, colors, portability

I want to create my colors in a consistent way across both the Mac and iOS versions of my app.  According to CGColor.h, the function

```
CGColorCreate(CGColorSpaceRef space, const CGFloat components[])
```

is available on both platforms.  But it seems annoyingly heavyweight.  Is there an easier way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd probably just go with:

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
#define HSBA(h,s,b,a) [UIColor colorWithHue: h saturation: s brightness: b alpha: a]
#else
#define HSBA(h,s,b,a) [NSColor colorWithHue: h saturation: s brightness: b alpha: a]
#endif

id tangerine = HSBA(0.084,1.0,1.0,1.0);
```

Another choice is:

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
#define MYCOLOR UIColor
#else
#define MYCOLOR NSColor
#endif

MYCOLOR *tangerine = [MYCOLOR colorWithHue:0.084 saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:1.0];
```

Yet another choice would be creating your own function. :)

Comment: As far as I can tell, NSColor does not have a .CGColor property.

Comment: If you need a CGColor property you should be able to find a category to add it without much problem. That's not elegant, of course, but I assumed you were looking for a simple per-invocation. :) This looks like it might work: http://forrst.com/posts/CGColor_Additions_for_NSColor-1eW